# In Single run Enter different values in edit box using QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I need to create one QTP script where i am filling a request form where two dates fields present.
1.Start Date
2.Wished Date

one functionality is like when ever user put 3 week future date & keep wished Date empty the status of request becomes "Awaiting"
Second functionality is like keep Start Date as empty & enter the wished Date(Tomorrow+) so status of request becomes "Urgent"

i already have a function which fills the request form and create request but i need to know that how i can achieve both of this functionality with the same run.

Note : In one run My script is creating 4 types of Request and for every Request the Form is same.

Answer (score 0):

The general response to anyone wanting to write logic once but vary the data is that you need to externalize your data.

Perhaps the easiest option is to use the built-in data table to drive your test (either the global or per-action data table sheet).  The QTP help file has all the details about how to use data tables, so I won't repeat that here.  You could create two columns of data... one for "Start Date" and another for "Wished Date".  You could then create one row of data for each test combination you wish to execute.  The two scenarios you described would be similar to:

Scenario 1:
Start Date = Some date 3 weeks in the future
Wished Date = Empty

Scenario 2:
Start Date = Empty
Wished Date = Tomorrow

The QTP data table is based on Excel, and you can use Excel formulas to help calculate dates that are not hard coded (e.g. Tomorrow = "TODAY() + 1" in Excel).